# Is there a name for relations that are compatible with composition and union?

Tags: set-theory, terminology, lattice-theory

I’m dealing with relations on relations $\mathcal{R} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(A \times A) \times \mathcal{P}(A \times A)$ that have the following properties:

- $(R_{1}, S_{1}) \in \mathcal{R} \mathrel\wedge (R_{2}, S_{2}) \in \mathcal{R} \rightarrow (R_{1} \circ R_{2}, S_{1} \circ S_{2}) \in \mathcal{R}$
- $(\forall i \in I. (R_{i}, S_{i}) \in \mathcal{R}) \rightarrow \bigl(\bigcup_{i \in I} R_{i}, \bigcup_{i \in I} S_{i}\bigr) \in \mathcal{R}$

Is there a common name for such relations?

Comment: You can view the set of relations as a quantale and these would be quantale congruences.

Comment: That’s interesting. Thanks for the hint. However, wouldn’t $\mathcal{R}$ need to be an equivalence relation in order to be a congruence? In my use case, $\mathcal{R}$ typically isn’t symmetric and might not even be reflexive or transitive.

Comment: Sorry. I missed it wasn't an equivalence relation.  I'm sure quantale people have a name for that